# RecyclerView messing up when setting visiblity in items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and have a `button` in each item. when pressing `button` it will hide or show other items. I'm getting data from the server when the user presses the button and I am setting visibility `visible` and if press again it will hide. it works fine,

but the problem is when I press `button` let's say `pos 3` it shows data but when I scroll down the `pos 7` item also get visible with same data! I'm really confused. why does this happen? and yes I searched over few article and I set else part also to set visibility gone. any help would be appreciated!

Here is some code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final pending_order_viewHolder holder, final int position) 
{
         final model_completed timeLineModel = mFeedList.get(position);
        //setting some data on start inlusding a button
        holder.mOrder.setText(timeLineModel.ordno +"");
        holder.mMarchant.setText(timeLineModel.olnm);

       //button click to expand and show data also hide when press agine
        holder.ButtonHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View m) {
             if(holder.ClickToHide.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

                //hiding if press the button agine
                 holder.ClickToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 holder.mDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             holder.mOrder.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
           holder.mMarchant.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
         }else {
              loader = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
              loader.setCancelable(false);
              loader.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.wait_msg));
              loader.show();

              //getting data when user expand
             ComplatedOrder(timeLineModel, holder, position);

         //setting visble with data
       holder.ClickToHide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      holder.mOrder.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.order_id, 0, 0, 0);
    holder.mMarchant.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.pending_outlets, 0, 0, 0);
       }
   }
});
```

getting server data class:

```
 private void ComplatedOrder(final model_completed timeLineModel, final pending_order_viewHolder holder,final int position){

     //here getting some data

    //setting data
holder.mTime.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.dilvered_at) + timeLineModel.deltime + "");
    holder.collected_cash.setText("₹ " + timeLineModel.amtcollect + "");
    holder.Custmer_name.setText(timeLineModel.custname + "");
    holder.mDeliver_at.setText(timeLineModel.custaddr + " ");
    holder.mDate.setText(timeLineModel.dltm + "");
    loader.hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in recycle view it will reuse the object, So if you set pos 3 as hide, it's trying to use the same object at pos7.

We can solve by storing the hide position in the adapter and in bind view each time show or hide based on the position.

like this

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final pending_order_viewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final model_completed timeLineModel = mFeedList.get(position);


//setting order no. and marchant name on start
        holder.mOrder.setText(timeLineModel.ordno + "");
        holder.mMarchant.setText(timeLineModel.olnm);


//click to expand and hide when press agine
        holder.ButtonHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View m) {
                if (holder.ClickToHide.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    holder.ClickToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.mDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.mOrder.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    holder.mMarchant.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

                    timeLineModel.isEnabled = false;
                } else {
                    if (timeLineModel.custaddr == null) {
                        loader = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
                        loader.setCancelable(false);
                        loader.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.wait_msg));
                        loader.show();

//getting data when user expand
                        ComplatedOrder(timeLineModel, holder, position);

                    } else {
                        timeLineModel.isEnabled = true;
                    }

                    notifyDataSetChanged();
//                    holder.ClickToHide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    holder.mDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                    holder.mOrder.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.order_id, 0, 0, 0);
//                    holder.mMarchant.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.pending_outlets, 0, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        });
        holder.collected_cash.setEnabled(false);


        if (timeLineModel.isEnabled) {


            holder.ClickToHide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.mOrder.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.order_id, 0, 0, 0);
            holder.mMarchant.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.pending_outlets, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            holder.ClickToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.mOrder.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            holder.mMarchant.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);


        }
    }
```

and ComplatedOrder method

```
private void ComplatedOrder(final model_completed timeLineModel, final pending_order_viewHolder holder,final int position){

    //here getting some data

    //setting data
    mFeedList.get(position).custaddr = Data.get("cadr").getAsString();
    mFeedList.get(position).custname = Data.get("cnm").getAsString();
    mFeedList.get(position).deltime = Data.get("dtm").getAsString();
    mFeedList.get(position).dltm = Data.get("dltm").getAsString();

    mFeedList.get(position).isEnabled = true;

    notifyDataSetChanged();


    loader.hide();
}
```

Comment: nice idea! could you explain a bit more? i need store position in a variable and set position when user press button and show data only on same position items?

Comment: I did small mistake in my example please check now.

Comment: Dont remove any item in mFeedList

Comment: now all getting visible with no data at start and when i press button its just showing the data. and still other row also getting same data :(

Comment: Post you complete adapter so that I can check and help you

Comment: And also i need to check how you are adding data to adapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148113/discussion-between-muthukrishnan-rajendran-and-fajar-khan).

Comment: Thank yolu so much

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest removing FINAL from

   onBindViewHolder(final pending_order_viewHolder holder, final int position)
2. if you are in a pinch try this

   holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
   in your adapter.

hope any one these suggestions helps you.

Comment: the second one is working but the clicked items get visibility gone when scrolling

Comment: make sure to update the current data, recycle view will redraw based on that data.

Answer (score 0):

You have your model class model_completed, what you can do is you create a boolean field in your model to store visibility.

**Add the following property to your model:**

```
    public class model_completed {
       ...
       ...
       ...
       //Add this property
       public boolean isVisible;
    }
```

**And modify your onBindViewHolder code as below:**

```
    holder.ButtonHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View m) {
         if(timeLineModel.isVisible){

            //hiding if press the button again

             //Set property to false
             timeLineModel.isVisible = false                 

             holder.ClickToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             holder.mDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         holder.mOrder.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
       holder.mMarchant.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
     }else {
          loader = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
          loader.setCancelable(false);
          loader.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.wait_msg));
          loader.show();

          //getting data when user expand
         ComplatedOrder(timeLineModel, holder, position);

     //setting visble with data

    //Set property to true

   timeLineModel.isVisible = true;

   holder.ClickToHide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.mDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  holder.mOrder.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.order_id, 0, 0, 0);
holder.mMarchant.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.pending_outlets, 0, 0, 0);
   }
  }     
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code, it's not working, the other items also get visible when pressing a specific button

Comment: The idea behind my post is basically you have to store the visibility as a part of your model! My exact code won't work, you have to save the visibility and make a check for it according to your requirements